# Querying Freebase for entitities containing more than one word

Tags: semantic-web, freebase

I am tinkering with Freebase search api. I am searching for entities and interested in scores returned by Freebase.
According to http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Search_Service , score is defined as

**score:** the score of this result - scores are out of 100

If my query contains only one word, like nirvana, score returned is under 100, but if I query something like 'statue of liberty' score is as high as 1100. Sample query link:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=statue%20of%20liberty&indent=true

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are wrong, the scores can be higher than 100 and they are only relevant when compared with other scores within the same result/response.